# Unity3d Circle Collider: How to rotate Game Object but don't rotate collider

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a `GameObject` with `CircleCollider2D` attached. When the `Collider` hits another `Collider` the GameObject starts moving and rotating (it has `Rigidbody2d` attached). I need to not rotate this GameObject, but rotate another GameObject with exactly the same forces `collider`&`rigidbody` calculated after hit.

Comment: I have some ideas, but first, I haven't done a 2D game yet, so can you tell me which dimension the collider rotates in? Does it stay flat (and just spin), or does it roll (and get out of its plane)?

Comment: @piojo The `GameObject` with `Collider` attached rotates only in Z dimension. It starts moving in X and Y dimensions. So after hitting with another `Collider` the `GameObject` starts moving and rotating (`Rigidbody`'s drag and velocity properties)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem, could you just have the `CircleCollider2D` on an otherwise empty GameObject and then have your GameObject (with the `rigidbody`) as a child of it?

Comment: @AdamH It sounds like he wants the collider/rigidbody to impart rotation to the game object, but not rotate itself. My answer attempts to have the game object "steal" the rotation/position from the physics object, then reset the physics object's rotation. (Though I have no clue why he wants the physics object to not rotate, considering that it's not visible anyway.)

Comment: @George Now that I mention it, why do you want the collider to not rotate? A circle has rotational symmetry, plus colliders aren't even visible. Is there some algorithmic need for this, or have we all misunderstood?

Comment: @piojo yes you are right. I don't want the gameobject with collider/ridibody to rotate, but it should impart rotation to another gameobject after collisions. Reason I need it because the collider doesn't match the sprite exactly (CircleCollider2D has offset center). So I moved sprite to another gameobject, and collider to another.

Answer (score 0):

Would this hack work?: Put the collider on a child object (not visible). Then every frame in `LateUpdate()` (so it will be late, but before rendering), do the switching: move the parent object to where the child object has been moved to (including the rotation), then reset the child object: put its local position to zero, and put its world rotation to the same thing it was a moment ago.

Like this:

```
void LateUpdate()
{
    Transform child = transform.GetChild(0);
    Quaternion oldRotation = transform.rotation;
    // Take the collider object's position/rotation
    transform.rotation = child.rotation;
    transform.position = child.position;
    // Restore the child's position to be at the same place as the parent
    child.localPosition = Vector3.zero;
    // Leave the child's rotation what it originally was:
    child.rotation = oldRotation;
}
```

One problem I see right now is that this may do funny things with momentum. I'm not sure. I don't know the effects of moving/rotating a physics object like this. You might want to play with using `Rigidbody.position=` and `Rigidbody.rotation=` to update the child's state (after you steal it for the parent).